# Regular expression to extract a text in double quotes and the the number behind

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string as below:

Yes- "Yes" 325/113 AND Relationship - "Buyer" OR Question Response - EQUAL TO (CASE INSENSITIVE) Yes- "Yes" 325/898

How can I extract the string **"Yes" 325/113** and **"Yes" 123/898** by using regular expression?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow, could you add what you've already tried ?

Comment: Is the text supposed to be `Yes` every time ?

Comment: I tried /".*?" [\/0-9]{1,20}/ but it returns Yes- "Yes" 325/113 and "Buyer" OR Question Response - EQUAL TO (CASE INSENSITIVE) Yes- "Yes" 325/898. I expect "Yes" 325/113 and "Yes" 325/898

Comment: Hi @robinvrd, The value inside "" is any content as long as it's inside the ""

Comment: Would [`"\w+"\s\d+\/\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/VRVPO4/1) work?

Comment: Hi @YevgenGorbunkov, thank you so much, it works but if I have a comma inside the "" (e.g. "Yes, test"), how can I customize your regex?

Comment: `/"\[a-z,]+"\s\d+\/\d+/gi`

Comment: Well for one thing `"Yes" 123/898` is going to be quite impossible to find since it does not even exist in the sample string you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should match your needs.

```
"([^"]+)"\s(\d+)\/(\d+)
```

> You can use [https://regex101.com/](https://regex101.com) to help on you on that.